# Server side rendering generating different markup than client side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am doing server side rendering using `express` and `react-router`:

This is my code on the server side:

```
app.use(
    express.static(
        path.join(__dirname,'public')
    )
);

app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.get('*',function(req,res){
   debugger;
   match({
       routes:routes,
       location:req.url,

   },(err,redirect,props) => {
       debugger;
       if(err)
       {
           res.status(500).send(err.message);
       }
       else if(redirect)
       {
           res.redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search);
       }
       else if(props)
       {
           const markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>);
           debugger;
           res.render('index',{markup});
       }
   });
});
```

These are my `routes`:

```
const routes = (<Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}>
                <Route path="/repos/:username/:reponame" component={Repo}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Route>);
```

This is my Repos component:

```
const Repos = ({children,},context) => {


    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const username=event.target.elements[0].value;
        const repo = event.target.elements[1].value;
        const path = `/repos/${ username }/${ repo }`;
        event.target.elements[0].value='';
        event.target.elements[1].value='';
        context.router.push(path);
        console.log(path);
    }

    return (<div>
        <ul>
            <li><NavLink to="/repos/reactjs/react">React</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/repos/reactjs/react-router">React Router</NavLink></li>
            <li>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="userName"/>{' '}
                    <input type="text" placeholder="repo"/>{' '}
                    <button type="submit">Go</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul> 
        {children}
    </div>)
};

Repos.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

When I render the `repos` route, I find that this error occurs when rendering the `input` element:

```
bundle.js:1658 Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
 (client)  data-reactid="10"><li data-reactid="11"
 (server)  data-reactid="10"><ul data-reactid="11"warning @ bundle.js:1658_mountImageIntoNode @ bundle.js:20285ReactMount__mountImageIntoNode @ bundle.js:7742mountComponentIntoNode @ bundle.js:19941perform @ bundle.js:8231batchedMountComponentIntoNode @ bundle.js:19955perform @ bundle.js:8231batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:16495batchedUpdates @ bundle.js:7389_renderNewRootComponent @ bundle.js:20108ReactMount__renderNewRootComponent @ bundle.js:7742_renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ bundle.js:20185render @ bundle.js:20205React_render @ bundle.js:7742(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:649__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:556(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:579(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:582
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information in your post for me to know what exactly is going wrong.

But what I find helps debug this is some simple `console.log` statements in your client.  Wherever your client bootstrap code is that calls `ReactDOM.render()`, do something like this:

```
const root = document.getElementById("root");

// add these console.log lines
console.log("before");
console.log(root.innerHTML);

ReactDOM.render(<...whatever.../>, root);

// add these console.log lines
console.log("after");
console.log(root.innerHTML);
```

Now you can copy those 2 lines of html into a diff tool or text editor and see where they differ.

*Usually* the difference is because the server renders with different state than the client.